# customr binding KO.js dropdownlist error

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

js to create form  I have problem with dropdownlist I have custom bind to populate the year and car set and they are not working because I ndo't know what is the problem with 
  ko.bindingHandlers.passengerSeatingDropdown and ko.bindingHandlers.passengerSeatingDropdown

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "yearsDropdown: function (){return years }"
> Message: years is not defined I donpt know how to fix it
> ```

js file

```
$(function() {

    function Car(data) {

        this.Id = ko.observable(data.id);
        this.Manufacturer = ko.observable(data.Manufacturer);
        this.Make = ko.observable(data.Make);
        this.Year = ko.observable(data.Year);
        this.Colour = ko.observable(data.Colour);
        this.PassengerSeat = ko.observable(data.PassengerSeat);

    }


    function CarViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.Manufacturer = ko.observable();
        self.Make = ko.observable();
        self.Colour = ko.observable();
        self.PassengerSeat = ko.observable();
        self.Year = ko.observable();
        self.Cars = ko.observableArray([]);


        self.AddCar = function() {
            self.Cars.push(new Car({
                Id: self.Id(),
                Manufacturer: self.Manufacturer(),
                Make: self.Make(),
                Colour: self.Colour(),
                PassengerSeat: self.PassengerSeat(),
                year: self.Year()

            }));

            self.Id(""), self.Manufacturer(""), self.Make(""), self.Colour(""), self.PassengerSeat(""), self.PassengerSeat(""), self.Year("")

        };


        self.AddCar = function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Cars',
                type: 'POST',
                data: ko.toJSON({ data: self.Cars }),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Car add to DB");
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new CarViewModel());
    });


ko.bindingHandlers.yearsDropdown = {

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var years = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        for (i = new Date().getFullYear() ; i > 1900; i--) {
            // Add each option element to the select here
            $(element).append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }
    }
};


    ko.bindingHandlers.passengerSeatingDropdown = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var passengerSeatingNumbers = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            for (var i = 2; i > 8; i = i + 2) {
                // Add each option element to the select here
                $(element).append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
            }
        }
    };
});


  <h2>Car Edit</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-horizontal"> 

            <fieldset>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="carManufacturer" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Manufacturer</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" id="carManufacturer" name="carManufacturer" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Manufacturer" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carManufacturer -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="carMake" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Make</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" id="carMake" name="carMake" class="form-control" data-bind="value:Make" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carMake -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="carYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select id="carYear" name="carYear" class="form-control" data-bind="yearsDropdown: years ">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carYear -->


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="carColour" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Colour</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" id="carColour" name="carColour" class="form-control"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carManufacturer -->


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passengerSeating" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passenger Seating</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select id="passengerSeating" name="passengerSeating" class="form-control" data-bind="passengerSeatingDropdown: passengerSeatingNumbers">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <br />

            <div><p class="bg-info">Click Cancel button to return to  list of Cars </p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                <input type="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"  data-bind="click: AddCar"/>
                <input type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset" />
            </div>
            <!-- /buttons -->
            <%--</form>--%>
        </div>
        <!-- /form -->
    </div>
    <!-- /col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /row -->
```

Comment: It looks like you are not doing anything with var years in your ko.bindingHandlers.yearsDropdown binding? If that is the case your html should be data-bind = "yearsDropDown :{}"

Comment: rather passing `{}` try to do like this `yearsDropDown :true` fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/91epn1ag/ . always useful if we want to switch things true/false .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working sample - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/3Lcc16hu/1/

From the code you have posted, it looks like you don't need any input parameters for your custom binding. It returns option elements for year from current year to 1900. If this is the case, try doing the following.

Html binding

```
<select data-bind="yearsDropdown : {}">

</select>
```

knockout custom binding handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yearsDropdown = {

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

          for (i = new Date().getFullYear() ; i >= 1900; i--) {
            // Add each option element to the select here
            $(element).append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }
    }
};
```